# calling WCF service using HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, wsdl, dotnet-httpclient

Can anyone tell me how can I manually create SOAP request to call a WCF service using HttpClient.

all I have is WCF service wsdl file so by using that wsdl file I should figure it out what kind of soap request service accepts and I should develop that request that using C# code.

Below is the WSDL file:

```html
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" name="Service1" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:55922/Service1.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://tempuri.org/"/>
</xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="IService1_GetData_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetData"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="IService1_GetData_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetDataResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="IService1_getemployeeSalary_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:getemployeeSalary"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="IService1_getemployeeSalary_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:getemployeeSalaryResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="IService1">
<wsdl:operation name="GetData">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/GetData" message="tns:IService1_GetData_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetDataResponse" message="tns:IService1_GetData_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="getemployeeSalary">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/getemployeeSalary" message="tns:IService1_getemployeeSalary_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/getemployeeSalaryResponse" message="tns:IService1_getemployeeSalary_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" type="tns:IService1">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="GetData">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/GetData" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="getemployeeSalary">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/getemployeeSalary" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="Service1">
<wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_IService1">
<soap:address location="http://localhost:55922/Service1.svc"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use `HttpClient` for this?

Comment: You can use Visual Studio's Add Service Reference with the WSDL to generate a client.  No need to do it by hand.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot, Tim:  we have a client who uses PerlAPI to call our service by creating SOAP request manually.They were able to call our ASMX service  but they are not able to call our WCF(we recently migrated ASMX to WCF) so to trouble shoot that i'm thinking to invoke our service using httpclient(httpwebreqest is not supposed to use in our firm) so that i can find sample xml which works!!!